# How can I change all instances of excel cells that have a specific character ( colon then letter)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet with 4500 lines (approximately).  I'm trying to replace all text that is `Envelope NameRANDOM` with `Envelope Name: RANDOM`.

Basically I need to add a `:`  between the phrase `envelope name` and a whole range of random actual names.

I did some research and found that there are wild cards in excel but I can't seem to find any useful way to discern usage for them.

**ADDITIONAL NOTE**
There are instances where it is already `Envelope Name: Random`. So if I did a simple search/replace that it would make those cells `Envelope NameEnvelope Name:`

Comment: Is this something you need the worksheet to do all by itself through a formula?  Or is this a one-time thing where you just need to clean up a worksheet?

Comment: I'm trying to clean up a data.  It won't be ongoing.

Comment: Have you tried to use Find/Replace?

Comment: Why do you need wildcards? Have you already tried the usual [**Find or replace text**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90) with the strings  **Find what:** `Envelope Name` and  **Replace with:** `Envelope Name: `?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that part.  There are instances where it is already `Envelope Name: Random`.  So if I did that it would make those cells `Envelope NameEnvelope Name:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand, you can just use Find and Replace twice.

Step 1:

```
Find:       "Envelope Name"
Replace:    "Envelope Name: "
```

Step 2:

```
Find:       "Envelope Name: : "
Replace:    "Envelope Name: "
```

The second step will correct any that were already correct but then got messed up by the first step.

Comment: this works. simple and easy.  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For a one-time application, I would not solve this with a formula.  I would use the built-in text replacement menu item.

With the spreadsheet open, click on cell A1 and then access the "Find and Replace" dialog either by:

- Pressing CTRL-H (on a PC, or the equivalent on a Mac); or
- On the `Home` ribbon, `Editing` Section, `Find&Select` > `Replace`

In the Dialog:

- `Find what:` Enter `Envelope Name`
- `Replace` with: `Envelope Name:`   (we added the colon and space here)

Now you have several options:

- `Replace All` will just go ahead and replace every instance
- `Find Next` will move one by one to the next successive instance, without changing an instance that is currently highlighted
- `Replace` will replace that one single instance and automatically find the next instance and pause.
- `Find all` will produce a list of every instance in the dialog box that you can scroll down to review

I recommend starting with `Find Next` and then manually pressing a few `Replaces` just to make sure you are getting desired results.  Once you are sure you are seeing the right result then press `Replace All`.  The dialog will show the count.

Be careful not to rerun the whole process again, as you would end up with `Envelope Range: :`  if you ran through them all again.

Comment: This works except I forgot to mention part of the messed up data...  There are instances where it is already `Envelope Name: Random`.  So if I did that it would make those cells `Envelope NameEnvelope Name:`

Comment: That’s actually easy to work around.  One way is to replace every instance of `name: ` with `name`, so now everything is the same when you run the replacement above.  It is also *very* common in text editors or in Excel to do a double switch.  For instance, changing every instance of a `Name: Random` to be something unique like `///` in order to simplify a lot of other replacements, and then changing `///` back to `Name: Random` at the end.  I end up doing this often in Notepad++, Word, and less so in Excel but it’s a common trick.